# How can one see which part of the code is running when button is pressed?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've started working on a big project and currently trying to understand the system. Is there any tool which I can use to see which part of the code is running when I press a button or a hyperlink, etc? I'm working on eclipse and the code is in java

Comment: Add a breakpoint on button press?

Comment: I was reading about debugging in eclipse here http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html
it says "To debug the program you need to define breakpoints." i.e. I need to show which part of the code it should stop on. While I'm asking how to see which  part gets activated while pressing a button, menu, etc? I'm not very proficient with debugger. If there is a way to do it with debugger please explain further

Comment: @JavaDevil I don't really know where is the hyperlink (actually it is not a button, i just said an example) in the code, as it gets created by user while the program is running

Comment: @RaviThapliyal what is KT? google didn't give anything relevant

Comment: KT: `Knowledge Transfer` to get a new resource on board and up to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific interfaces that must be implemented by classes that handle GUI events. Select the appropriate interface for the event you are interested in. Search for all classes implementing it. In each class, set a breakpoint or add logging in the overriding method that handles the event. Debug, and do the appropriate GUI action.

That should tell you which class actually handles the event in question. Look at its code. See what it calls. Experiment with more breakpoints or logging as needed.

Answer (score 1):

First put breakpoints where you want to see how it is working(For instance a button-clicked method).For this double-click the leftside of the line you want to debug.Then right-click on the application and debug as ...Then click the button you want to see.Program will break on the break point you put.You can see the values of variables.

Comment: it's really hard to find where is a specific button in the project. As the project is really big. Also, there are dynamic hyperlinks which are created by users while the program is running, i.e. there is no that specific hyperlink before running the program

Answer (score 0):

This may seem primitive but I just type in System.out.print() statements that print out the various variables when I want to see them. I use Eclipse too and this works for me. I couldn't understand the debug tool so this is what I did instead.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a bad idea. When moving to code to production you must remove all those lines and forgetting one may have fatal consequences. Instead use http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/ or something similar, then change those prints to debug level logs. That way they can be used both during development and when you have issues in production.